# Adding extension to VLC snap version

Tags: 16.04, vlc, snap

I have installed VLC version 3.0.1 using snap. I was trying to add an extension to it but could not understand how to add it.

More specifically, where to place the `.lua` file?

Comment: I have the same problem. The place should be "/snap/vlc/190/usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/" but it's a read-only filesystem

Answer (score 5):

The path I used to put the extensions in is that:
`~/snap/vlc/1049/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions`.

After that, to open the extension, you have two ways:

- Open VLC ---> View ---> *The extension name*.
- If VLC was already opened when you added the extension, then from Tools ---> Plugins and extensions ---> "Active Extensions" tab ---> Reload extensions. After clicking it, you should see the extension name added in that blank square above "Reload extensions" button. Now, you can open the extension like in the first method.

Answer (score 3):

The places to add an extension in Ubuntu 18.04 under snap are:

"/home//snap/vlc/365/.local/share/vlc/lua/intf/", 
"/home//snap/vlc/365/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/", 
"/home//snap/vlc/190/.local/share/vlc/lua/intf/", 
"/home//snap/vlc/190/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/"

where  is the user's folder under /home. The same *.lua files must be copied onto the /.../vlc/190/ and the /.../vlc/365/ folders.
This worked when I added the "Jump to Time" 3.0 extension to vlc 3.0

Comment: My answer before was mistreated by the website. I wanted to say "/home/<user>/" instead of "/home//" where <user> is the user's folder under home.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Go to Tools > Plugins and Extensions
Click on search more addons online and then find the extension. In my case I was looking for the Syncplay extension